# What does being "duckbilled" mean?

Tags: expressions

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duckbilled

> duck +‎ billed

> Having a bill like that of a duck.

The entry doesn't explain anything?

Comment: What does the bill of a duck look like?

Comment: What were you expecting? I'd say that "Having a bill like that of a duck." is a fairly consise description of the term.

Comment: Google `duck bill`

Comment: A bird has a beak, and a duck's beak shape is called a bill.

Comment: "The entry doesn't explain anything?" is an extremely vague question to begin with:  how we can address the omission of whatever you might think a possible explanation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overthinking it. It literally means, "has a bill like a duck".

The "bill" of a duck is the prominent hard beak:

[image]

So any other animal with a similar snout might be called "duckbilled".

For example, this is a *duckbilled platypus*:

[image]

There are groups of "duckbilled" dinosaurs as a similarly-shaped snout:

[image]

Comment: And this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck

Comment: DV for answering a very low-quality question.

Comment: Makes sense. I couldn't stop thinking about a "bill" as in something you have to pay. I thought it was supposed to be some kind of metaphor.